# Nonetype error when I'm being very careful

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some basic screenscraping, with BeautifulSoup. I'm fairly new to Python, and completely new to BeautifulSoup. So I might just be missing something, but I can't figure out why I'm encountering this error.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def get_page(url):
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    rval = resp.read()
    resp.close()
    return rval


def spider_stuff(tree_str):
    lable_to_location = dict()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tree_str)
    for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
        if tag is not None:
            print(type(tag))
            print(tag.get_text())
            print(tag.get('href'))
            lable_to_location[tag.get_text()] = tag.get('href')
        else:
            print('what?')
    return lable_to_location


print(spider_stuff(get_page('https://www.example.com/')))
```

I get this output:

```
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spider.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(spider_stuff(get_page('https://www.example.com/')))
  File "spider.py", line 17, in spider_stuff
    print(tag.get_text())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Add `print(dir(tag))` before attempting to access that attribute.

Comment: Make sure you've installed the `beautifulsoup4` package (not `beautifulsoup`). My guess is that the `get_text` method got added in version 4.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_text` attribute of the `tag` variable has a value of `None`, which means you can't try to use it to make a function call.

Answer (score 0):

My environment:

- Windows 8
- Python 3.6

I have installed beautiful soup 4 using as per [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I see the `urllib2` was not working with my Python version. So, I have changed it to `from urllib.request import urlopen`. Additionally, I have added `html.parser` parameter in `BeautifulSoup`.

Finally your code now looks like:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_page(url):
    resp = urlopen(url)
    rval = resp.read()
    resp.close()
    return rval

def spider_stuff(tree_str):
    lable_to_location = dict()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tree_str,"html.parser")
    for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
        if tag is not None:
            print(type(tag))
            print(tag.get_text())
            print(tag.get('href'))
            lable_to_location[tag.get_text()] = tag.get('href')
        else:
            print('what?')
    return lable_to_location
print(spider_stuff(get_page('https://www.example.com/')))
```

Output:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
More information...
http://www.iana.org/domains/example
{'More information...': 'http://www.iana.org/domains/example'}
```